# WordPress SQL table, search for value

Tags: sql, wordpress

Not 100% sure if this is best off here or in the WordPress stack but I'll give it a go here.  I have a custom database table called 'wp_sales' within my WordPress database.  Whenever somebody purchases an item the sale_id is written into the database using the following....

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "sales";
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'saleid' => $sale_id ) );
?>
```

This works great, what I am trying to do now is amend this so that before it writes to saleid it checks for it first to ensure there is not duplicate.

Is this just a straight SQL query I need to use?

Comment: why not adding a UNIQUE constraint on your saleid column? And handle the exception.

Comment: I had though about that but I need to run some additional logic afterwards and it seemed more efficient to try and do it as part of the check.  Or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the number of rows:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "sales";
$registered = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name WHERE saleid = '{$sale_id}'" );

if ($registered == 0) {
  $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'saleid' => $sale_id ), array('%s')  );
}
```

EDIT: try to specify the format as stated [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows).

EDIT2 : For varchar you have to add quotes when you do the select and specify %s for the format when you insert it.

Comment: I have tried that but for some reason it is creating duplicates and not stopping them

Comment: maybe try to specify the format, I updated my answer for that.

Comment: Same as before, it just keeps adding duplicate records.  It's like the sql query isn't working for some reason although it all looks ok

Comment: in your table, saleid is in INT (not in VARCHAR)?

Comment: No its varchar because the saleid contains letters as well ie; TH473648X

Comment: I have tried setting the format to string and it's still creating duplicates